# Получить сумму столбца всех записей

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Доброго времени суток!

Есть две таблицы: product_type и product.

Между ними связь через foreign key product.product_type_id references product_type.id

[image: Таблица Типа продукта]

[image: Таблица продукта]

Мне необходимо вывести сумму цены, для каждого типа продукта.

- Mobile phone 280
- Tablet       280
- TV           370

Comment: Интересно, какой смысл в сумме ЦЕН (не стоимостей)...

Comment: Что вы сделали для решения своей проблемы? С чем столкнулись?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  домашние задания нужно делать самостоятельно.

Comment: `select sum(price)  from product group by product_type_id` ? ну и не забыть остальные нужные поля

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей, за наводку. Вот что у меня получилось. select sum(product.price), product_type.name from product join product_type on product.product_type_id = product_type.id group by product_type_id